# Where can I get the codes about iocp in source code of asio?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, iocp

I wanted to learn how to use iocp perfectly, but I couldn't find the function `CreateIoCompletionPort`.
I explored all the files of asio, and only found few `.cpp` files!
How can/should I explore the source code?

Comment: I assumed you meant `boost::asio`. If not disregard my answer. Otherwise tag your question with `boost-asio`.

Comment: If you want to learn about IOCP-programming, I would advise you to lean about IOCP as a technology *first*. There are *plenty* of basic IOCP samples on the web that don't involve substantial depth that boost takes it. The boost source can be a quite daunting as a starting point for *anything* if you're unfamiliar with the technology underneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asio is highly templated library and all of the code lives in header files. You can find them [here](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio). The iocp related stuff that talks to underline OS can be found inside the [detail](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/asio/detail) folder.

To start you can take a look at implementation of deadline timer.

1. deadline_timer.hpp, typedefs:

   1. basic_deadline_timer.hpp, uses the service:

      1. deadline_timer_service.hpp, is implemented in:

         1. detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp, uses:

            1. detail/timer_scheduler.hpp, typedefs:

               1. detail/timer_scheduler_fwd.hpp, uses:

                  1. detail/win_iocp_io_service.hpp, includes,

                     1. detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp, where the actual implementation is.

:-)

Comment: yeah i got it.i think there must be some calls to function "CreateIoCompletionPort" but i didnt find that string in all of files.am i asking a stupid question ?

Comment: @KnowNothing, looks like i missed the impl file in my list. Take a look at: detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp